# Find coordinates in wikipedia pages iterating over a list

Tags: python, for-loop, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Probably this is a simple question, but my experience in for loop is very limited.

I was trying to adapt the solution in this page https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Geosearch with some simple examples that i have, but the result is not what i expected.

For example:

I have this simple data frame:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'City':['Sesimbra','Ciudad JuÃ¡rez','31100 Treviso','Ramada Portugal','Olhão'],
              'Country':['Portugal','México','Itália','Portugal','Portugal']})
```

I created a list based on cities:

```
lista_cidades = list(df['City'])
```

and i would like to iterate over this list to get the coordinates (decimal, preferably)

So far i tried this approach:

```
import requests

lng_dict = {}
lat_dict = {}

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

PARAMS = {
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "titles": [lista_cidades],
    "prop": "coordinates"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()
PAGES = DATA['query']['pages']

for i in range(len(lista_cidades)):
    for k, v in PAGES.items():
    
        try:
            lat_dict[lista_cidades[i]] = str(v['coordinates'][0]['lat'])
            lng_dict[lista_cidades[i]] = str(v['coordinates'][0]['lon'])
    
        except:
            pass
```

but it looks like the code doesn't iterate over the list and always returns the same coordinate

For example, when i call the dictionary with latitude coordinates, this is what i get

```
lng_dict



   {'Sesimbra': '-7.84166667',
 'Ciudad JuÃ¡rez': '-7.84166667',
 '31100 Treviso': '-7.84166667',
 'Ramada Portugal': '-7.84166667',
 'Olhão': '-7.84166667'}
```

What should i do to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your for loop. Your `DATA` contains only one city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query returns only one result, it will take only the last city from you list (in your cas the "Olhão" coordinates).

You can check it by logging the `DATA` content.

I do not know about wikipedia API, but either your call lack a parameter (documentation should give you the information) or you have to call the API for each city like :

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Sesimbra', 'Ciudad JuÃ¡rez', '31100 Treviso', 'Ramada Portugal', 'Olhão'],
                   'Country': ['Portugal', 'México', 'Itália', 'Portugal', 'Portugal']})
lista_cidades = list(df['City'])

lng_dict = {}
lat_dict = {}

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

for city in lista_cidades:
    PARAMS = {
        "action": "query",
        "format": "json",
        "titles": city,
        "prop": "coordinates"
    }
    R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
    DATA = R.json()
    PAGES = DATA['query']['pages']

    for k, v in PAGES.items():
        try:
            lat_dict[city] = str(v['coordinates'][0]['lat'])
            lng_dict[city] = str(v['coordinates'][0]['lon'])
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for, but I thought it would return more results. Apparently it only returns results when the word is correct. I actually wanted/expected that could return the wikipedia page that has as title the closest possible to my name input. For example if I google "2000 Trevisto wikipedia", google returns the correct page. I thought it would do the same here. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: I do not know the Wikipedia API sorry, but this should probably be a solution : https://wikipedia-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html (you can check page existence)